# Java sorting algorithm (version as string)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have a list of version numbers as string

- 2_1.1.1_release
- 3-2_snapshot
- 3.2.1  <---the one I want
- 1.3(stable)
- 0.2(1_releaseCan)

each version is a String . I have split them by regular expression,
 save them into a collection of String[]s
collection
how do I design a algorithm to find the biggest version number?
NOTE 3.2 is less then 3.2.1 because 3.2 is equals to 3.2.0
yes any missing digit is seeing as 0

thanks all

Comment: ... Seems like a simple matter of sorting by multiple values, with each digit being a value.

Comment: dave newton : simple but where is the answer mate?

Comment: Vitalij Zadneprovski: what if some question doesn't have the right anwser? should I go and missleading people ?

Comment: @shanyangqu Pretty much strewn all over the web.

Comment: @ Dave Newton you can be such sarcastic, but can bother to type a few line of code. u sad mate

Comment: You should do this without any help from us, as a way of learning.

Comment: us means the rest of whole world? who are you , are you speaking as the god of internet?

Comment: @shanyangqu That's not sarcasm, that's literal: there are tons of multiple-value sorting examples, and that's what the answer to your question is. In the time it took you to get angry at me you probably could have coded it.

Comment: @DaveNewton so your suggestion to all the programmer need answer is : go and read your own book, if thats your point, the whole stackoverflow is pointless, you better off shut it down, then point everyone to buy books at amazon

Comment: @shanyangqu Dave suggested that you should spend more time searching for the solution (on Google, or here on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=version+sort)) before asking for it. There are a lot of answers to this problem already posted.

Comment: @buc how do you know I didn't? and how do you know I dn't have a answer? I just want better answers. if this answer is already posted . find it for me. I need exactly the same kind of question

Comment: too simple too answer is the worst answer on stackoverflow. I don't mind people say, oh~ its a simple question, but here we go thats the answer. if you like it, help us, don't like it or too insulting to even look at the question. just shut it, walk away

Comment: @Dave: no it is not as trivial as sorting by multiple values. No.

Comment: @shanyangqu My first response *is* to search, yes--it's the fastest, easiest, and most educational. IMO SO exists to answer questions that aren't obvious, or that can't be figured out after applying one's own intellect. I apologize if that approach bothers you.

Comment: @SalmanA Of course it is; that's what the problem is by definition, and both answers state as much.

Comment: @DaveNewton just let go this post mate, I feel sorry to waste your time on this. You mission is to develop a cutting edge program to solve the world peace. not on this sorry

Comment: @shanyangqu It's ironic that you accuse me of being sarcastic when I indicated what the nature of the problem was and that it was pretty straight-forward and you're the one being sarcastic and upset. Good luck!

Comment: @DaveNewton its ironic in terms of using the word "simple" 20 times, but can't spare a line of code to help?

Comment: @shanyangqu I used the word "simple" once--there's *already* example code. *My* approach to helping is to encourage people to figure out things on their own, particularly when prior art exists, rather than spoon-feeding an answer. You'd prefer a different approach, which is fine. You don't get to choose how people help, just like I don't get to choose the nature of questions people ask.

Comment: someone might find this interesting: [PHP `version_compare` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php). The description section roughly describes the "algorithm" for comparing version numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this comparator:

```
private static final Comparator<String[]> comp = new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compare(String[] arg0, String[] arg1) {
        int length = arg0.length;
        if (arg1.length>arg0.length) length = arg1.length;

        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            String s0 = null;
            if (i<arg0.length) s0 = arg0[i];
            Integer i0 = (s0==null)?0:Integer.parseInt(s0);
            String s1 = null;
            if (i<arg1.length) s1 = arg1[i];
            Integer i1 = (s1==null)?0:Integer.parseInt(s1);
            if (i0.compareTo(i1)<0) return -1;
            else if (i1.compareTo(i0)<0) return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

and then use the arrays.sort() method: Arrays.sort(strings, comp);

Comment: thanks Justin, its very similar to my own approach. what I did was to padding all the missing digits, to match with the length of the longest version number. then compare with the array element one by one. I am looking for smarter answers. but yeh very nice solution. thanks mate

Comment: This is slightly better then your version since it'll essentially pad at most one digit. For example: comparing 1 to 1.1.1. This algorithm will pad 1 to 1.0 and then stop since the if check will return when 0 is less than 1. Where your algorithm will pre-pad 1 to 1.0.0.

Comment: aha, you point accepted. I will leave it for a day. otherwise your answer is best version so far. all the best mate

Comment: Also, now that I think about it. Your approach would have to loop three times to sort the list. The first loop to find the max length, the second to pad all the strings, and the third to sort the list. I guess you could merge the second and third loops but it's still at least two loops.

Answer (score 4):

Although not optimal, but straightforward solution

```
public class VersionComparator implements Comparator<String>  {

  public int compare(String version1, String version2) {
    // Split version into parts
    String parts1[] = getVersionParts(version1),
           parts2[] = getVersionParts(version2);

    // Go through common prefix left to right, first part which is higher indicates
    // higher version (4.2.1 > 4.2.0 > 3.9.9)
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Math.min(parts1.length, parts2.length); i++) {
      int partComparison = compareVersionPart(parts1[i], parts2[i]);
      if (partComparison != 0){
        return partComparison;
      }
    }

    // Common prefix is the same; longer value means higher version
    // (3.2.1 > 3.2)
    if (parts1.length > parts2.length) {
      return 1;
    } else if (parts1.length < parts2.length) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }

  }

  protected String[] getVersionParts(String version) {
    return version.split("\\.");
  }

  protected int compareVersionPart(String part1, String part2) {
    int versionPart1 = Integer.parseInt(part1),
        versionPart2 = Integer.parseInt(part2);

    if (versionPart1 > versionPart2) {
      return 1;
    } else if (versionPart1 < versionPart2) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

}
```

Then you do something like `Arrays.sort(versions, new VersionComparator())` and pick last element.
UPDATE: `Collections.max()` would be better alternative.

Comment: sorry I might not said it clear, version can be 3-1.2 or 1.2(RELEASE)or 1.3_STABLE thats why I parse it to string[] first so we get nicely arragned [1,2,3,4] etc.... simply compare string doesn't work in my case –

Comment: have a closer look - this code does not compare the whole string, it splits it into parts and then compares them one-by-one, those of higher order first; you may need more sophisticated regexp to split version string, and more clever ways of comparing individual bit - so getVersionParts() and compareVersionPart() should be really adapted to your specific version format.

Answer (score 0):

The comparator's algorithm goes like this:

```
public int compare(String a, String b) {
    Integer a1 = firstPart(a);
    Integer b1 = firstPart(b);

    int res = a1.compareTo(b1);

    if (res != 0) 
        return res;

    return compare(remainingParts(a), remainingParts(b));
}
```

You just have to implement *firstPart* and *remainingParts*. You can then use *Arrays.sort*.

Comment: Changed the type of firstPart to Integer. You should implement firstPart in a way that it returns an Integer representation of the first section of the version, e.g. firstPart("3.21") returns 3, reaminingPart("3.21") returns "21

Comment: You need to consider leading zeros in numbers after the first decimal. 3.02 is less than 3.1; comparing 02 and 1 as integers won't work (comparing as string might work).

Comment: From my understanding 3.1 is lower than 3.02 (which is 3.2), but higher than 3.0.2 Maybe we need a more concise definition of the ordering. If the parts have a string ordering then *firstPart* should return a String.